# Objective-c recursive blocks with threads EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, recursion, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have some recursive block code in objective-c that is causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
- (void) doSomethingWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
    if (completion) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);
    }
}

- (void) testBlocks {

    NSString *testString = @"hello";

    __block NSInteger count = 0;

    __block __weak void (^weak_block)(NSString *);
    void(^strong_block)(NSString *);
    weak_block = strong_block = ^(NSString *str) {

        [self doSomethingWithCompletion:^{
            NSLog(@"number: %zd", count);
            if (++count < 10) {
                weak_block(str);
            }
        }];


    };
    strong_block(testString);
}
```

The error happens on weak_block(str) which i assume is because it is released when dispatch_async is called. Calling strong_block(str) in it's place when it's declared with __block like so:

```
__block void(^strong_block)(NSString *);
```

Causes a warning 'Capturing 'strong_block' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle'.

So I changed the testBlock method to not use a weak reference like so:

```
- (void) testBlocks {

    NSString *testString = @"hello";

    __block NSInteger count = 0;

    __block void (^inner_block)(NSString *);
    void(^strong_block)(NSString *);
    inner_block = strong_block = ^(NSString *str) {

        [self doSomethingWithCompletion:^{
            NSLog(@"number: %zd", count);
            if (++count < 10) {
                inner_block(str);
            }
        }];


    };
    strong_block(testString);
}
```

But I am unsure if this causes a retain cycle or if adding

```
__block void (^inner_block)(NSString *) = weak_block;
```

inside the block instead would cause a retain cycle as well. What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: My brain hurts from looking at this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because the block (pointed to by `weak_block`, `strong_block`) has already been deallocated by the time the "completion" block runs, and calling a block with a `nil` block pointer crashes.

The block is deallocated because there are no strong references to it after `testBlocks` returns.

The second one will have a retain cycle because the block captures `inner_block`, which holds a strong reference to itself.

The proper way is to make a strong reference from the captured weak reference inside the block, and let the completion block capture that:

```
- (void) testBlocks {

    NSString *testString = @"hello";

    __block NSInteger count = 0;

    __block __weak void (^weak_block)(NSString *);
    void(^strong_block)(NSString *);
    weak_block = strong_block = ^(NSString *str) {

        void(^inner_block)(NSString *) = weak_block;
        [self doSomethingWithCompletion:^{
            NSLog(@"number: %zd", count);
            if (++count < 10) {
                inner_block(str);
            }
        }];


    };
    strong_block(testString);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, my bug was I was using: typeof(weak_block) inner_block = weak_block; instead of void(^inner_block)(NSString *) = weak_block; which made it weak instead of strong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is proof of either possibility but if you add a `weak` block property and examine that one after all block stuff has run...

```
...
@property (weak) void (^true_weak_block)(NSString *);
@property (weak) NSString *weak_string;
...


- (void) testBlocks {

NSString *strong_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"some string"]; // note that you can not use a string literal in this example..
self.weak_string = strong_string;    

NSString *testString = @"hello";

__block NSInteger count = 0;

__block void (^inner_block)(NSString *);
void(^strong_block)(NSString *);
inner_block = strong_block = ^(NSString *str) {

    [self doSomethingWithCompletion:^{
        NSLog(@"number: %zd", count);
        if (++count < 10) {
            inner_block(str);
        }
    }];


};
self.true_week_block = strong_block;
[self test];
strong_block(testString);
}

- (void)test {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", self.true_week_block); // not deallocated
        NSLog(@"%@", self.weak_string); // deallocated
    });
}
```

In my test the block is never deallocated and also the memory address remains the same over time, even if you change regular assignment of the two strong blocks to use copy instead of the implicitly retained assignment.

Comment: Hey I think being a property of the class the true_weak_block wouldn't be released until that class has been released right? or am i just confusing myself here?

Comment: If it works like a regular object it would work as expected here since assignment to weak won't pup the refcount so when the original reference goes out of scope it will be deallocated.

Comment: Updated with s test with a regular object.

Comment: Yup thats right! But putting self.true_weak_block(str); in place of inner_block(str); still causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: Yes, looks like either the compiler notices it's not being used inside the block ant therefore don't put it in block storage or the fact that its not used, inside the block, renders it from being retained. If you just put a check `if(inner_block){self.true_weak_block(str);}` it "works" as before.

Comment: And if you remove any references to any strong blocks inside the block the true_weak_block is `nil` when the test method runs.